# Yii2 showing records label

Tags: php, pagination, yii2

I created a page with custom pagination. All I want to know is how can I add a label that shows how many records that was being displayed.

here is my custom pagination page:

[image]

and this what I want to achieve:

[image]

like that.

Source of pagination: http://tutorials.scrisoft.com/how-to-use-pagination-in-yii-framework-2-0/

heres my view:

```
<?php foreach ($s as $sc): ?>  
    <div class="row2">
        <div class="cell">
            <?= $sc->de ?>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <?= $sc->s ?>
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            <?=$sc->be?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
        endforeach;
    ?>
<?= LinkPager::widget(['pagination' => $pagination]) ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$totalCount = $pagination->totalCount;
$begin = $pagination->getPage() * $pagination->pageSize + 1;
$end = ($pagination->getPage() + 1) * $pagination->pageSize;
 if ($end > $totalCount) {
   $end = $totalCount;
 }
$page = $pagination->getPage() + 1;
$pageCount = $pagination->pageCount;
```